# Disable setter based on other field value. Annotation

Tags: java, annotations, interceptor

I'm trying to disable the value of some fields on a class based on other field value, I want to make it using some kind of annotation or Interceptor.

```
@Entity
public class Order{

    private String street;

    private boolean sent;

    public void setStreet(String street){
         if(!sent){
              this.street = street;
         }
    }
}
```

This kind of logic is used in several fields and I'm now looking for a more elegant and clear way of doing this via field or method annotation.
Something like:

```
@Entity
public class Order{

    @NotSent  
    private String street;

    private boolean sent;

    //Or maybe @NotSent
    public void setStreet(String street){
         this.street = street;
    }
}
```

I think Interceptors may be the way to go but I don`t know how to access other fields values inside it, and also don't know if it is a good idea to surrownd almost every Entity setters with an interceptor because of performance or any other thing.
Sorry for possible spelling or grammar mistakes.

Comment: what is meant by disable ?

Comment: What if the value of `sent` is changed **after** `setStreet(...)` was already called?

Comment: By disable I mean do not change the value of the property

Comment: Andrew that is not a problem, if sent is false the value of street can be changed, if sent is true the value of street can not be changed.